# htaccess multiple directories and GET params

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm developing a site in PHP and running it locally on my machine with MAMP for testing purposes. Right now I'm trying to clean up the URLs for the backend area(admin) to produce URLs like:

```
localhost/admin/products/read/1
```

This is my `.htaccess` in root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^admin/products/read/([0-9]+)/?$ admin/products/read.php?id=$1 [NC]
```

I've also been trying this `RewriteRule` whilst removing the last line of the code above:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/(products|users|companies)/(read|update|delete)/(.*)$ /$1?id=$2 [NC,L]
```

Folder structure:

```
htdocs
 - admin
  - products
   - read.php
   - update.php
   - delete.php
   - index.php
  - users
   - ...
  - companies
   - ...
index.php
```

Chrome and Safari are throwing 404 not found when trying URLs such as

```
localhost/admin/products/read/1
localhost/admin/products/read/1/
etc..
```

All help is appreciated!

**Update 31/08/18**

With MrWhite's help I scribbled together this, from his answer, to expand the scope in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)/(.*)/([0-9]+)/?$ admin/$1/$2.php?id=$3 [L]
```

Which got me thinking, could I keep the config file cleaner by just checking for the query `ID` and then rewrite?

Comment: "could I keep the config file cleaner by just checking for the query `ID` and then rewrite?" - Not quite sure what you mean? Only you know what URLs you are trying to catch. But if you are only rewriting a handful of URLs (eg. `read`, `update`, `delete`, `index`?) and they all follow the same pattern as above then you may not need the catch-all rewrite that follows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got your directives in the wrong order. You are also missing some `L` flags. And you need to make sure that `MultiViews` is not enabled.

Try the following instead:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^admin/products/read/([0-9]+)/?$ admin/products/read.php?id=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

By having the directives the other way round, it would be appending the `.php` extension to the URL-path and never matching your second directive.

Also, once the directive has matched, you don't want processing to continue so you need the `L` (`last`) flag.

Comment: Your updated _generalised_ directive looks OK. Although, with any regex, it is preferable to be as specific as possible. So, for example, if the second path segment should only be lowercase a-z, then change `(.*)` to something like `([a-z]+)`.

Comment: Thanks for the edit on my post, I will apply your input on any further Stackoverflow posts!
I also updated my question since I want the RewriteRule to have a broader scope.